# Kitaev chain for an odd number of electrons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, lattice-model, majorana-fermions

Kitaev  shows in ["Unpaired Majorana fermions in quantum wires"](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0010440) how unpaired Majorana fermions arise at both ends of a chain of $N$ electrons, where $N$ is even.

After a quick literature search, I could not find anybody considering $N$ to be odd. I would naively assume this case would have a Majorana fermion at one end of the wire only.

Why is the case of $N$ odd not interesting?

Comment: Do you really mean $N$ electrons, or do you mean $N$ fermionic modes?

Comment: I understood the paper to start with a chain of an even number of electrons but could be wrong.

Comment: It says "Let N be the total number of fermionic
sites in the system". But where does it say that $N$ is even?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch You are correct - $N$ even is not stated. I assumed $N$ was even because the calculation shows how the "fermionic sites" pair up in two different ways. I am confuzed as how an odd number of "fermionic sites" could pair up?

Comment: What pairs up are Majorana modes (fermions), not "proper" fermionic modes. For each fermionic mode, there are two Majorana fermions.